# Play audio after recording using Phonegap 2.9 and iOS7

Tags: audio, cordova, media, ios7, record

I'm having problem with Phonegap 2.9 and iOS7. Using the Media API, the recording works, but the file seems to be blocked (even after using release()) and I can't play it. The same script works fine on iOS 5/6 and Android. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have a Phonegap 2.9 app that records audio using the Media object. I am able to save it to the file system, play it, encode it, and upload it to a server. So it is possible to get it working. If you have any code samples you could post, that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on that issue and let you know. Also, you can try this path

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html

Comment: Thanks Nisar, but unfortunately I can't use 3.0 for this project.

Comment: iOS 7 doen't support 2.9. Phonegap 3.0 working fine. But Memory leak issue is there in iOS7

Comment: I've deployed 2.9 for iOS 7 with no problem.